# printf precision

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I am writing a program in C and I have several printf statements for debugging. Is there a way to change the precision for a HEX output on printf? Example. I have 0xFFF but I want it to print out 0x0FFF.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say `printf("%04X", x);`.

The `0` means "pad with zeros", the `4` means "at least four characters wide".

For integers, one doesn't use the term "precision" (because integers *are* precise), but rather "field width" or something like that. Precision is the number of digits in scientific notation when printing floats.

Comment: Actually, you *can* specify a precision for the integer conversion specifiers: `printf("%.4X", x");` does so, and works as expected (for the `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x` and `X` conversions, the precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear).

Comment: Yeah, but the word "precision" doesn't really apply -- you always see the exact integer.

Comment: The word "precision" is actually used in C for this though, even for integers - the `.4` part of `%.4X` is called the precision.

Comment: It would be better to use `%.4x`, i.e. use the *precision* instead of the *width*. The width includes other stuff like space for the sign, the `0x` (if `#` flag is used), etc.

Comment: I wonder where (in glibc's manual page) this is explained (formatting `0x618` with `%#04x` gives `0x618` (and not `0x0618`), but formatting with `%#0.4x` gives `0x0618`.
The manual page says: "If  a  precision  is  given with  a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored."

Comment: @U.Windl It's in the manpage, in the paragraphs about precision and width. The `0` of in `0x0618` for `%#0.4x` is because of the precision.  If you increase the width, e.g. to `printf("%#010.4x\n", 0x618);`, it'll print `    0x0618`, showing that the `0` flag is indeed ignored. If you remove the precision (`printf("%#010x\n", 0x618);`), it'll change to `0x00000618`.

Comment: @PSkocik: I'd like to give you a +1, but that's not possible. Your comment was very enlightening!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the precision field for printf when printing in hex.

For instance:

```
int i = 0xff;
printf ("i is 0x%.4X\n", i);
printf ("i is  %#.4X\n", i);
```

Will both print:
0x00FF

Comment: This way of doing it results in EXACTLY the same answer as Kerrek, although uses printf flags slightly differently

Comment: Slightly (50%) more verbose than the common %04X