# c++ which format is used in this swprintf()

Tags: c++, format, printf

What format does this specify in `int swprintf (wchar_t* ws, size_t len, const wchar_t* format, ...);` ?

```
L"x%04.4x "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A break-down of the parts:

- the `L` prefix [specifies a wide format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087219/what-exactly-is-the-l-prefix-in-c) (`wchar_t *`, as opposed to `char *` in `[s]printf`)
- the leading `x` is not part of the format specifier, same as the trailing space
- `%x` results in a hexadecimal representation of the argument
- the `0` specifies the padding - i.e., if the given number is less than the  specified number of digits (see next bullet point), it will be padded with 0s
- the `4` after that gives the width, i.e. the printed number of digits (but including extra characters such as `0x`, in case for example the `#` prefix would have been given as well)
- `.4` - 'precision' for floating points, for integers it is the (minimum) number of printed digits

See also for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701332/printf-precision), and myriads of other format specifier resources, e.g. on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Note that the combination of a width and a precision can lead to unexpected results; the precision is considered for the number of digits (including the number of `0`), and the width is used for the width of the resulting string; examples:

```cpp
wprintf(L"x%2x\n", 0x618);
wprintf(L"x%.2x\n", 0x618);
wprintf(L"x%0.3x\n", 0x0618);
wprintf(L"x%0.4x\n", 0x0618);
wprintf(L"x%01.4x\n", 0x618);
wprintf(L"x%04.4x\n", 0x618);
wprintf(L"x%010.4x\n", 0x618);
wprintf(L"x%010x\n", 0x618);
```

Output:

```
x618
x618
x618
x0618
x0618
x0618
x    0618
x00000618
```

So as you can see, a "width" less than 4 doesn't change anything about the output, unless the precision also decreases (but a precision less than 3 also does not decrease the number of digits shown, as it wouldn't be possible to represent the number with less digits).

And in the next-to-last line, you see the effect of a large value for width but low precision; the output is right-aligned, but with spaces instead of 0 as prefix.

Comment: Specifying a *wide* format string seems strange; AFAIK the format string is very much *specified* to be a multibyte string, not a wide one. A compiler extension perhaps? As for the answer, perhaps mention that the leading `'x'` and trailing `' '` are not part of the conversion specifier.

Comment: @DevSolar `swprintf` (in question body) wants a wide string, `printf` (in question title) wants a multibyte string.

Comment: @Cubbi: Ah, missed that "w" in the body. Cheers.